# how to convert JSONArray to string/float values

Tags: java, android, json, okhttp

I am building an android app that uses HTTP request for consuming web API. I've made request pretty easily, everything works fine, but I can't find a way to convert the JSONArray that I am getting into single Float x, Float y values.
Any help would be welcome.

How the API looks :

[image]

My code:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray price = jsonObj.getJSONArray("price");

                for(int I = 0;  I < price.length(); I++) {
                    Float x ;
                    Float y ;

                    values.add(new Entry(x,y)); // add one entry per hour
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use following way:

```
JsonArray jArr = price.getJSONArray(I);
values.add(new Entry((float)jArr.getDouble(0), (float)jArr.getDouble(1)));
```

Also the `price` you need to retrieve should be in jsonObject instead of another array.

Comment: thanks for response! new Entry accepts only Float values, but there is no getFloat option, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @VaclovasRekašiusJr. you can change Entry type, any way check update, you can get value of float.

Comment: thanks for you response, really helped me a lot. But update your answer with changing this line 
values.add(new Entry((float) jArr.getDouble(0), (float) jArr.getDouble(1)));

Removing boxing, and just casting to float works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @VaclovasRekašiusJr. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with like:

```
private void getPricesArray(){
    ArrayList<Double[]> pricesDoubleArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < pricesDoubleArray.size(); index++) {
        pricesDoubleArray.get(index)[0] = Double.valueOf(16748584949L); //
        pricesDoubleArray.get(index)[1] = 4506.45; //
    }
}
```